# How do I install 32-bit packages on 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, multiarch

I am using the 64-bit version of Ubuntu, but I need to install a 32-bit version of a package to use with a proprietary extension for it, which is only available in 32-bit. How can I install the 32-bit version of the package, while I am running a 64-bit system?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that, nor do I think the answer listed there provides the answer to this question.

Comment: @dobey, why not?  It's exactly what this question is asking for.

Comment: @psusi Because that question (and the answer) is all about `ia32-libs` and is a very long diatribe about multiarch and ia32-libs going away, and doesn't simply answer the question of how to install a 32-bit package, directly.

Comment: @dobey, no, the answer is about installing the i386 version of the program instead of the older ia32-libs.

Comment: @psusi I don't know what question and answer you're reading to get to that, but the other question is about how to run a 32-bit program on 13.10 where there is no ia32-libs any longer, and has nothing to do with installation. Running a program, and installing a program, are two very different things.

Comment: @dobey, quoting from the other answer: "you can install any library using the apt-get syntax. Just add :i386 to the library you want to download, and done"

Answer (score 0):

To install the 32-bit version of a package, you simply need to use `package:i386` when installing the package, rather than simply `package`.

For example, to install the 32-bit version of `r-base` you would run `sudo apt-get install r-base:i386`.

Comment: and package dependencies?

Comment: Dependencies are pulled in automatically by apt.